# I need to prove: if $a|b$ and $a|c$ then $a|(bc)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

what I did:
$ak=b$,
$aj=c$ so
$bc= ak \times aj= a^2(kj)$.

Let $m=bc$  and  $n=kj$
Hence, $m= a^2n$ which is:  $a^2|m
= a^2|bc  \leftarrow$  The proof must have been $a|bc$ !
Help?

Comment: hint: $a|a^2$ always.

Comment: Note that you can prove a stronger statement: if $a$ divides $b$, then $a$ divides $bc$, whatever $c$ is.

Answer (score 2):

$a\mid b \to b = ak, a \mid c \to c = am \to bc = a(akm) \to a \mid bc$

Comment: Thanks a llot..Understood sir!

Comment: You are welcome, buddy.